# AppleScript to block Safari pop-up windows

Tags: macos, safari, automation, applescript

I am trying to automate the blocking of pop-up windows in Safari.
I have tried the following defaults write operation

```
defaults write com.apple.Safari WebKit2JavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically -boolean false
```

But this fails to do it. I have also tried setting it as true but even that didn't help. I am currently trying to find a way to do it using AppleScript.
This is what I have written so far -

```
CMD_ACTIVATE='tell application "Safari" to activate'
CMD_NEWTAB='tell application "System Events" to keystroke "," using {command down}'
osascript -e "$CMD_ACTIVATE" -e "$CMD_NEWTAB"
```

This opens up the preferences but then I draw a blank. Anyone with any suggestions on how to proceed? Also I don't really need a solution to this only in AppleScript any other way to do it would also be helpful.

Note: I have been using Mac OS only for a week now, and am not that well versed in the nuances of this OS, so please be a bit descriptive when answering. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blocking pop-up window is done via Safari / preferences / tab Security where you need to set the correct checkbox.

This preference seems to be stored in your library / preferences file com.safari.plist which contains the flag com.apple.Safari.ContentPageGroupIdentifier.WebKit2JavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically with value Yes when pop-up are blocked.

However, it may not be the only place to be changed and in any cases, it is not officially documented, so that place can be changed by Apple any time. This is not recommended to use it.

Going back to Applescript, because Safari is quite poor in terms of applescript handling events, you are forced to go via GUI scripting. That’s what you’ve started, but keep in mind that if Apple changes the layout of Safari preference window, your script must be reviewed.

When going through GUI scripting (which, again, should only be when no other solution found) you must understand structure of GUI objects. Window contains button, check box, tool bar... in a hierarchy model. For instance the preference window in Safari contains bellow the tool bar, an object "group 1" with itself contains many objects depending of the tool bar current selection. Once you understand that concept, the script below, which does what you're looking for, will be easy to understand with many comments:

```
tell application "Safari" to activate
tell application "System Events"
keystroke "," using {command down}
delay 0.2 -- leave sometime to open window
tell window 1 of process "Safari"
    click button 6 of toolbar 1 -- Security button is number 6
    delay 0.2
    -- check if check box not yet set and set it.
    if (value of checkbox 5 of group 1 of group 1) = 0 then click checkbox 5 of group 1 of group 1
end tell
delay 0.2
click button 1 of window 1 of process "Safari" -- click on red / close button
end tell
```

I am running on Safari 10.0.3. If your version is different, the preference window may be different. Then the script must be adjusted: the Security tab button may not longer be the number 6 in your version,...

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. But I am running into a few problems. I am running Safari 9.1.2 and in this version Security tab has a total of only 5 checkboxes and blocking pop-up window option is the 3rd one. Leaving that aside It does not even change tabs the step where you have written `tell window 1 of process "Safari" click button 6 of toolbar 1`

Comment: Sorry just this statement is giving a error `tell window 1 of process "Safari` and the error is `144:145: syntax error: Expected end of line but found “"”. (-2741)⁠⁠⁠⁠`

Comment: That's what I mentioned in my answer : any difference in Safari windows layouts force GUI to be changed.I made this with Safari 10.0.3 and you must adjust it to the layout of your preferences window in 9.1.2. Also, check that command "," is also opening preferences window in your version. About the syntax error, if a " is missing, it is probably because you did not copy correctly the script. check that all opening " has its closing ".

Comment: The script you provided works when run through script editor even with my different version of safari. But when i try to run it through bash, I get a host of accessability errors. Anyway thanks for the script.